# Generating function for product of terms in a sequences

Tags: generating-functions

For motivation, consider multiplying a polynomial by the geometric series:

$$ \frac{P}{1-x} = \sum a_i x^i \sum x^j = \sum c_kx^k$$

By the cauchy product rule,

$$ c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i$$

Now, we find that the coefficents of this new polynomial are the sum of first $k$ terms, but what I wish to know is there a function $Q$ such that:

$$ QP = \sum c_k a^k$$

WIth the property that

$$ c_k = \prod_{i=0}^k a_i$$

That is it is the product of first $k$ terms?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Presumably you mean $\prod_{i=0}^k a_i$. Take $a_i = i + 1$; then $c_k = (k+1)!$ whose generating function has zero radius of convergence.